# Solving differential equation $m\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=-b\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)^{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have problems to solve the following differential equation:

$$m\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=-b\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)^{2}$$

Where $v$ is a function of $x$, ie $v(x)$. While $x$ is a function of $t$, $x (t)$.

My idea was to use the chain rule to solve this, then:

$$m\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=-b\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)^{2}$$

Accordingly:

$$m\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-b\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)$$

However, here is no longer to do, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what is your question ?.

Comment: It can solve the last equation? Or something wrong in my procedure?

Comment: The problem has a solution?

Comment: is $v = \frac{dx}{dt}$?

Comment: Yes, indeed $v=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$

we can re-write the equations as

$$
m\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}} = -b\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^{2}
$$

as you already showed.

$$
mv\frac{dv}{dx} = -bv^{2}
$$
which results in
$$
\int \frac{1}{v}dv = \mathrm{ln}v = -\frac{b}{m}x + \lambda
$$
therefore the solution for v is
$$
v = v_{0}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{bx}{m}}
$$
now you can get $x(t)$ by integrating

$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = v_{0}\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{bx}{m}}
$$
where $v_{0} = \mathrm{e}^{\lambda}$, and is determined by initial conditions.
$$
\int \mathrm{e}^{\frac{bx}{m}}dx = \frac{m}{b}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{bx}{m}} = v_{0}t + \lambda_{1}
$$
where $\lambda_{1}$ is another integration constant, determined by initial conditions.
This yields 
$$
x(t) = \frac{m}{b}\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{b}{m}v_{0}t + \lambda_{1}\right)
$$